# Add multiple Templates in one Yield

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to add multiple Bootstrap Modals in one Yield.

```
Router.route('test', {
    yieldTemplates: {
        'contentTemplate': {to: 'content'},
        'modal1Template': {to: 'modal'},
        'modal2Template': {to: 'modal'}
    }
});
```

This code adds only the last template to the yield -modal-. Is it possible to add multiple templates to one yield or do anybody know a best practice for this situation?

Comment: If you don't have an excessively large number of combinations to join together in that way, why not make a third template that just joins them in the way you intend?

Comment: Although it does work for me sometimes, I still want to have a multi yield functionality like asked, since I create packages with templates that can have multiple plugins in 1 section